# Длительное нажатие button как осуществить?

Tags: c++, c++builder, button, radstudio, android-on-click

среда разработки: RADstudio c++builder (разработка под android)

я вычитал что нужно сделать обработчик onClick и в нем уже проверять сколько времени была нажата button, это правильно? если нет то как нужно?

Если через события onkeydown и onkeyup, то как это сделать, не могу в голове представить

Comment: А разве у вас нет раздельных обработчиков на press / release?

Comment: есть onKeyDown/up. может это они?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Назначаете обработчик на оба упомянутых вами события. При onkeydown запускаете таймер, у которого таймаут предварительно настроен на нужное время ожидания. Если событие таймаута произошло раньше, чем onkeyup, то выполняете нужные вам действия. Если произошло событие onkeyup, то отключаете таймер.

Answer (score 2):

При нажатии получить текущее время и сохранить его в переменную. При отпускании снова получить текущее время и вычесть из него сохранённое ранее время нажатия. Полученная разница и будет равна продолжительности нажатия. Для удобства можно задействовать функции SecondsBetween, MillisecondsBetween (в зависимости от требуемой точности) из DateUtils:

```
#include <DateUtils.hpp>

TDateTime pressTime;

void __fastcall TForm1::ButtonMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, float X, float Y)
{
  pressTime = Now();  
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ButtonMouseUp(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, float X, float Y)
{
  __int64 duration = MillisecondsBetween(Now(), pressTime);
  ShowMessage("Кнопка была нажата " + IntToStr(duration) + " миллисекунд");
}
```